# Tuning a comparison of two columns against a set of integers

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance, performance

Having this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE detail.element_id IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 8) AND
      (
        detail.additionalelement_id IS NULL OR
        detail.additionalelement_id IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
      )
```

What kind of index/object can we create to optimize the query's performance?
How would you rewrite this clause in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And create an index on both `detail(element_id)` and `detail(additionalelement_id)` and let postgres decide which to use.

(Edited to remove using `coalesce(detail.additionalelement_id, -1)`)

Comment: The coalesce "trick" here will prevent the optimizer from using the index for additionaelement_id.  The original question's example WHERE clause is better for using the index.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it all again. the indexes made the work, not the coalesce. Thank you Bohemian and Matthew

Comment: @MatthewWood Oops! It was late. It looked good. But you are right. I've edited the answer